# NHibernate: Calling .RemoveAll on a collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a problem with not being able to use `.RemoveAll` when retrieving a collection via NHibernate.

I have an entity called `Order` that I persist via NHibernate.

`Order` has many `OrderItems`. Here is my mapping for this relationship:

```
mapping.HasMany(o => o.Items)
                   .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                   .AsList()
                   .Inverse();
```

In my domain that look like this:

```
public virtual IList<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
```

As I understand it, I have to use `IList` because NHibernate has it's own implementation of List.

Now I want to remove an item from my `Order` using this method on in my `Order` class:

```
public virtual void RemoveItem(string variantSku)
{
    items.RemoveAll(x => x.Variant.VariantSku == variantSku);
}
```

It doesn't work, because `IList` does not have this method.

I tried:

```
items.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Variant.VariantSku == variantSku);
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I realise the `items.ToList()` actually creates a copy of the original list, so I guess I could try:

```
var itemsList = items.ToList();
itemsList.RemoveAll(...)
```

But then does it still persist via NHibernate?

My question: can I actually use `.RemoveAll` in this context or should I be thinking about a different way to remove an item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the collection mapped as the inverse side of the relationship, so in addition to removing the item from the collection you have to nullify the reference to the Order on the OrderItem side. Therefore the RemoveAll method, or the extension method, won't do the job.

I would handle it like this:

```
public virtual void RemoveItem(string variantSku)
{
    var itemsToRemove = items.Where(x => x.Variant.VariantSku == variantSku).ToArray();
    foreach(var item in itemsToRemove)
    {
       item.Order = null;
       items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

I also suggest using set instead of bag mapping.

Comment: I'm not sure you need item.Order = null if you've got .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan() in the mapping, do you? Isn't that what AllDeleteOrphan() does? The rest is spot on though. Was making the schoolboy mistake of foreach'ing over items and trying to remove.

Comment: item.Order = null is what makes it an orphan, otherwise it would be re-saved when the session is flushed.

Comment: Actually your code doesn't work. You will still get an exception: “Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.” I ended up using a for loop.

Comment: The ToArray should copy the elements to a new array and prevent the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 3):

You could always create your own `RemoveAll` extension method:

```
public static void RemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> source, Predicate<T> predicate)
{
    // TODO: Argument non-nullity validation

    // Optimization
    List<T> list = source as List<T>
    if (list != null)
    {
        list.RemoveAll(predicate);
        return;
    }

    // Slow way
    for (int i = source.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (predicate(source[i]))
        {
            source.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I would *expect* NHibernate to care about the collection itself - just removing an item from  a `List<T>` isn't something that NHibernate can "notice".

Of course, if you didn't want NHibernate to care about what you do - if your changes were only *meant* to be local - then your final piece of code would be fine.

Comment: Aha, so the tag "C#" attracts the great Jon Skeet, aka Master of the Stack, himself ... good to know :) ... I do need NHibernate to know care about this operation.

Comment: @autonomatt: In which case, assuming the returned collection is happy to remove items using `RemoveAt`, this should be fine.